# Как сделать вызов WebApp Telegram из бота на чистом php?

Tags: php

Так я отправляю пользователю кнопки, а как сделать что бы открывалось web приложение?

$keyboard = array(
'inline_keyboard' => array(
array(
array(
'text' => 'Да',
'callback_data' => 'nearest_yes',
),

```
                    array(
                        'text' => 'Нет',
                        'callback_data' => 'nearest_no',
                    ),
                )
            ),
        );

        SendTg($wp_user_id, $reply_message, $keyboard);
```